# Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2 update error

Tags: android-studio-3.0

Error:/build/intermediates/incremental/mergeDebugAndroidTestResources/merged.dir/values/values.xml:3 invalid color
Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.internal.aapt.AaptException: AAPT2 compile failed:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I have faced this issue on Android Studio 3.0 Canary 2, I got a solution [here](https://github.com/ArthurHub/Android-Image-Cropper/pull/291).

Just replace `<item name="ic_back_api" type="drawable"/>` with `<item name="ic_back_api" type="drawable">@null</item>`